# Why does this CASE not do as expected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

This query fails to do as intended. Here's my example code:

```
create table #test (last_name varchar(20), plan_name varchar(60))
insert #test values ('Alanis', 'Alanis UT Standard Bulk Cut (DRP)')

select last_name
    , plan_name
    , case when plan_name like '''' + last_name + '%''' then SUBSTRING(plan_name, len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+1, len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+25) else isnull(plan_name, 'NA') end
from #test
```

Now what I'm expecting this to do is if the `plan_name` starts with the `last_name`, lop off the front part so I'm left with the text of the `plan_name` minus that prefixed `last_name`. But this doesn't work for some reason. It just spits out the `plan_name` without any change at all.

If I code more explicitly, it works just fine:

```
select last_name
    , plan_name
    , case when plan_name like 'alanis%' then SUBSTRING(plan_name, len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+1, len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+25) else isnull(plan_name, 'NA') end
from #test
```

I've even attempted using a `QUOTENAME()` function instead of my manual concatenation and I get the same result. I verified that my source table's column is in fact a `varchar` data type (for both the `last_name` and `price_plan`). I'm assuming I'm missing some detail, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: `case when plan_name like last_name + '%'`? Otherwise you are expecting the value for `plan_name` to include enclosing single quotes. Do `SELECT '''' + plan_name FROM ...` to see what I mean.

Comment: Your code evaluates a name that starts and ends with a single quote.

Comment: [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7c932ee57a975807f29c612c346e06e0) might illustrate the difference.

Comment: I'd be careful with do a blind `replace()`. What if you have a short surname like say "Tan" that could easily appear multiple times within the larger string?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `last_name` is within the single quotes, remove those extra quotes and this will work.

```
select last_name
    , plan_name
    , case when plan_name like '' + last_name + '%' then SUBSTRING(plan_name
        , len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+1, len(ltrim(rtrim(last_name)))+25) else isnull(plan_name, 'NA') end
from #test
```

Another suggestion is to use sql `replace` function instead of `substring`

```
select last_name
    , plan_name
    , case when plan_name like '' + last_name + '%' then replace(plan_name, last_name, '') else isnull(plan_name, 'NA') end
from #test
```

Comment: I don't think there's a reason to have the empty string either. Am I missing something?